# Uncountably many disjoint closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if I can find in a topological space uncountably many pairwise disjoint nonempty closed sets, then the space is not separable? I know it is true for open sets (from ccc), but for closed too?

Answer (score 5):

No, a point is a closed set in the usual topology on $[0,1]$ therefore
$$[0,1]=\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]} \{x\}$$
provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that this is a misremembering of the following true statement: a <strike>first</strike> SECOND-countable space cannot have an uncountable *discrete* subspace.

Comment: Of course it can: an uncountable discrete metric space is a counterexample (there are many others). Maybe you mean "second countable" (= having a countable base), in that case it would be true.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma this is why i should never use the word "misremembering"